# select multiple lines using the linux command sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have an example [file] that I want to Grab lines 3-6 and lines 11 - 13 then sort with a one line command and save it as 3_6-11_13. These are the commands I have used thus far but I haven't gotten the desired output:

```
sed -n '/3/,/6/p'/11/,/13/p file_1 > file_2 | sort -k 2 > file_2  & sed -n 3,6,11,13p file_1 > file_2 | sort -k 2 file_2.
```

Is there a better way to shorten this. I have thought about using awk but have I stayed with sed so far.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `sed` you're allowed to specify addresses by number like so:

```
sed -n '3,6p'
```

The `-n` is to keep `sed` from automatically printing output.

Then you can run multiple commands if you're using `gsed` by separating those commands with semicolons:

```
sed -n '3,6p; 11,13p' | sort -k2 > 3_6-11_13
```

Comment: Thank you Tim Pote. I used a slightly modified version of what you suggested. I had actually tried what you suggested earlier in the day but I kept getting an error do to me not using a semi-colon after '3,6p;. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

sed combine multiple commands using -e option

```
$ sed -e 'comm' -e 'comm' file.txt
```

or you can separate commands using the semicolon

```
$ sed 'comm;comm;comm' file.txt
```